# Why is my twisted plugin not appearing when I run the `twistd` command with no options?

Tags: python, twisted, twistd

Here is the current state of my `twistd` plugin, which is located in `project_root/twisted/plugins/my_plugin.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from zope.interface import implements

from twisted.plugin import IPlugin
from twisted.python.usage import Options
from twisted.application import internet, service

from mylib.io import MyFactory


class Options(Options):
    """Flags and options for the plugin."""

    optParameters = [
        ('sock', 's', '/tmp/io.sock', 'Path to IO socket'),
    ]


class MyServiceMaker(object):
    implements(service.IServiceMaker, IPlugin)

    tapname = "myplugin"
    description = "description for my plugin"
    options = Options

    def makeService(self, options):
        return internet.UNIXServer(options['sock'], MyFactory())
```

- There is **no** `__init__.py` file in `project_root/twisted/plugins/`
- The output of `twistd` doesn't show my plugin when run from the project's root directory
- I installed my library via `python setup.py develop --user` and it is importable from anywhere

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suspected, it was something *very* simple:  I needed to instantiate an instance of `MyServiceMaker`, so simply adding `service_maker = MyServiceMaker()` at the bottom of the script fixes the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem... but I had not forgotten the thing you did.